# Java Linked List implementation (from AbstractList) gives nullPointerException on Collections.sort

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, abstract

I am a newbie in Java and OOP, the previous language that I've learned being C.
I am trying to create a Linked List that extends AbstractList and that allows the usage of Collections.sort() function. The problem is that when I call the Collections.sort() function, I get a nullPointerException. My guess is that the exception resides from the fact that the last node in my list is a null one (so I can know where the list ends).

```
class Node
{
    Object o;
    Node next;
    public Node(Object n)
    {
        o = n;
        next = null;
    }
}

class LinkList extends AbstractList
{
    Comparator c;
    public Node head, last;
    public LinkList(Comparator c)
    {
        this.c = c;
        head = null;
        last = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object a)
    {
        Node t = new Node(a);
        if(last == null)
        {
            head = t;
            last = t;
            last.next = null;
        }
        else //thanks, hyde
        if(last != null)
        {
            last.next = t;
            last = t;
            last.next = null;

        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object get(int a)
    {
        Node it = head;
        int contor = 0;
        while(it!=null && contor<a)
        {
            it = it.next;
        }

        if(it!=null)
        {
            return it;
        }
        else
            return null;
     }

@Override
public Object set(int i, Object a)
{
    Node it = head;
    int contor = 0;
    Node aux;
    while(it!=null && contor<i)
    {
        it = it.next;

    }
     if(it!=null)
     {
        aux = it;
        it.o = a;
       // Collections.sort(this,c);
        return aux;
     }
     else
        return null;
}

@Override
public int size()
{
    Node it = head;
    int contor = 0;
    while(it!=null)
    {
        contor++;
        it = it.next;
    }
    return contor;
}

@Override
public int indexOf(Object a)
{
    Node it = head;
    int contor = 0;
    while(it!=null && it.o.equals(a)==false)
    {
        it = it.next;
        contor++;
    }
    if(it!=null)
    {
        return contor;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkList lista = new LinkList(new Comparator(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
             int s1 = (int) o1;
             int s2 = (int) o2;
             return s2-s1;
        }
        });
        lista.add(2);
        lista.add(3);
        Collections.sort(lista); //this is line 156
        System.out.println(lista.size());
    }
}
```

Basically, I add two elements and I try to sort the list and I get the nullPointerException. It feels very frustrating, because I have no control over the sort function.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
at Ex6.main(Ex6.java:156)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code of `java.util.ComparableTimSort`, but somehow, I don't think it's going to be able to work by just calling `add`. Please show more of your methods.

Comment: Your add method adds first node twice.... Use *else*.

Comment: @RobinGreen: added the rest of the methods.

Comment: @Robertfrost this is not related to your problem, but `if(it!=null)
        {
            return it;
        }
        else
            return null;` is pointless - just `return it;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `contor++` in the loop inside the `get` method so it always returns `null`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for pointing that out. Now I get the Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable exception. Does this mean that I have to make Node implement Comparable and override the compareTo method?

Comment: @Robertfrost hmm... I think actually you shouldn't return the `Node`s from `get`, because they are an internal implementation detail of your data structure. If you had used generics, this problem would have been more obvious.

Comment: Good point. I should have returned the object stored in the node.